# Core php routes is not defined but working

Tags: php

http://localhost/abc/category/my-accessories-44/

this code is written in php core, as this is called from 
as
category/my-accessories-44/
but there no file and folder with category name, how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the route was manipulated from .htaccess.